# CSS: How to fix one panel and scroll the other?

Tags: css, html

I have a web page with two panels.  The left panel takes up the majority of of the width and displays user posts.  The right panel is a navigation menu so I want it to remain fixed and never roll off the screen.

When there are too many posts to fit on one screen, a scroll bar appears on the right of the screen (NOT the panel), and the user scrolls down.  This is all good, except that the navigation menu scrolls off the screen.

Both panels are within a common div.  I tried setting its position to relative, then making the nav panel position fixed, with a right offset of 0.  This kept the nav panel on the screen, but on the far right (ie. not within the containing div).

How do I go about keeping the nav panel fixed on the screen, but floated to the right of it's containing div?

Thanks a million!

EDIT: For and example of what I mean, look at Facebook.  You'll see that the posts column can extend on forever, but the right hand column (with the advertisements) stays on the screen...

Comment: Why do the two elements have to be within the same container div?

Comment: Alex, the main content area on the page is "main-display". That's the containing DIV.

Comment: And what happens when the navigation menu is taller than the screen/window (either the window got resized, mobile screen too small, text enlarged due to poor eyesight) and the user can't scroll to reach the items in the bottom? Be careful when you fix stuff

Comment: It sounds like it doesn't matter *how* this panel is constructed, when you have too many items, you will need two scrollbars (or a similar tool). Looks more like an usability issue. Why do you need such a big floating element?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Twitter Bootstrap Affix JS plugin:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix